# ECLIPSE: Classes are not being automatically copied to "build/classes" folder

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, classnotfoundexception, buildpath

After struggling to find out why the URL-Mapping was not working for one of my web classes (I was just getting the `ClassNotFoundException` all the time), I discovered that it's source folder was not automatically copied to `build/classes` folder, as it should.

I tried to manually copy it, but Eclipse seems to not recognize it (I was supposed to add it through the Eclipse interface, but, as you should know, the `classes` folder is not visible through Eclipse's package explorer). What should I do?

PS: I have other packages at this project which were coppied automatically to `build/classes`, no big deal.

PS2: If I right-click the class, I don't see the option to "add it to build path".

Comment: Is it a java project?  Just check that once

Comment: Do you mean access modifiers? If so, noups; the class is public.

Comment: when you make an eclipse project, you have an option of choosing the type of project

Comment: Sorry, I read "protect". Yes, it is a Java Web Project.